# Is there any way to find out result matching percentage in vespa.ai?

Tags: java, bigdata, vespa

We need to find out the result matching percentage, for example-

I am searching for an artist that is Coldplay and I queried as-

```
/search/?yql=select * from sources * where  artist contains 'Coldploy';
```

OR

```
/search/?yql=select * from sources * where  artist contains 'Coldplsy';
```

So I will get some matching percentage in result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/default-result-format.html - see totalCount and the coverage section - you can calculate matching percentage from the numbers there

Comment: Hi @kristian thanks for the reply, can you please explain with an example so I understand better.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Divide "totalCount" by "documents". Adjust using "coverage" (in case the full document corpus was not scanned). I think this gives you a fraction for dow many documents matched the query